# extract several strings with str.extract() method

Tags: python, dataframe

I can't find my way around rules for extracting several strings from the set of data.
For example, I need to extract COLORS (column) that are RED, BLUE and YELLOW. How do I need to build extract method to be:

`dataframe["COLORS"].str.extract(RED or BLUE or YELLOW)`

Comment: I found the following regex rule, but it doesn't meet my requirements:
A|B | Matches expression A or B. If A is matched first, B is left untried.

Comment: Could you give us some sample data of the top 5 rows?

And also are you looking to extract just the text from the COLORS column, or the row that correspond to RED, BLUE, YELLOW?

Comment: COLORS
blue
red
brown
yellow
green
purple
red

Comment: Above is example. I'm looking to extract the rows that correspond to values 'red', 'blue' and 'yellow'

Answer (score 0):

There's a number ways to do this, below I've illustrated one approach.

This will allow you to bring in the rows of data by your filter criteria.

```
color_filter = ["RED", "BLUE", "YELLOW"]

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv') # However you choose to read the data in

newdf = df[df["COLOR"].isin(color_filter)]

print(newdf)
```